# an empty widget is created when trying to iterate through a list and create widget in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to iterate through a list and render multiple widgets in flutter. my list has two items. the weird thing is that the two items get built but an emty space between them gets build too.
here is my code:

```
 Column(
            children: state.homePageData.categories
                .map((item) => Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.network(
                          baseUrl + item.img.toString(),
                          height: 100,
                          width: 100,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )))
                .toList(),
          )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an empty widget, but the image itself doesn't fill the container's height. Try adding `fit` property to the image widget. You can find more on FitBox enum [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html)